# CMake Error before its working perfectly now full of errors?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

CMake is working perfectly before when I formatted the laptop after trying to build the gradle for the first time i am getting errors in CMake I didn't understand why I am getting it tried checking all the questions related CMake but nothing helped me.

The project I tried to build was https://github.com/Keshava11/AndroidNDKDemos

[SDK Manager Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRhqV.png)

Error : https://anotepad.com/notes/45scm8

Comment: Please, add the error log into the **question post**, not *link* to it. This is **requirement** of Stack Overflow. You may format the error log like a code, by pressing `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: It looks like your username contains a space, which is typically a bad idea for development tools.

Comment: Thank you Botje, it worked for me....